# Connecting Maya 2011 with Mysqldb

Tags: python, mysql, maya

I am using Maya 2011(64bit) and MySQL 5.5 (64 bit) in Windows 7 (64 bit) machine. I tried to connect maya with Mysqldb through python. So i copied the connector files into maya\python\lib\site packages.

I was able to import MYsqldb module without any error. But when i tried call the cursor object (for querying), I found that Maya is not recognizing the cursor object.

Here is my sample code:

```python
import MySQLdb as mb
import maya.cmds as cmds

def mysql_connect(hostname, username, password, dbname):
    db = mb.connect(host=hostname,user=username,passwd=password,db=dbname)

db = mysql_connect("localhost", “root”, “test”, “mydbt")
dbcursor = db.cursor()
dbcursor.execute("select * from maya")
```

---

But the code throws the following error :

> Error: AttributeError: ‘NoneType’ object has no attribute ‘cursor’ #

I tried verifying the env-path variables, replacing the connector files but the problem persists.

Since being a beginner, i am un-able to identify the exact issue.
I request for your valuable suggestions

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning anything from `mysql_connect` function. So it returns `None`. When you do:

```
db = mysql_connect("localhost", “root”, “test”, “mydbt")
```

`db` becomes `None`. Try changing:

```
db = mb.connect(host=hostname,user=username,passwd=password,db=dbname)
```

with

```
return mb.connect(host=hostname,user=username,passwd=password,db=dbname)
```

That being said, I'm not sure defining a function to make a single thing is useful. Better to have something like this:

```
import MySQLdb as mb
import maya.cmds as cmds

db = mb.connect(host="localhost",user=“root”,passwd=“test”,db=“mydbt")

dbcursor = db.cursor()
dbcursor.execute("select * from maya")
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestion Avaris. Being a beginner i was struck with this step. Finally, i was able to learn about my mistake. Thank you Again. its working. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here, you have two things assigned to `db`. It appears that `mysql_connect("localhost", “root”, “test”, “mydbt")` is returning `None`, so when you call `db.cursor()` later, you get that error.

Make sure you're overwriting the `db` variable correctly (in this case, it looks like you aren't).

Comment: Thank you TorelTwiddler. I made a mistake in returning. I learned about this from avaris and your feedback. Thank you